# Segmentation fault when using toRaw()

Tags: ios, swift, segmentation-fault

Working on swift programming language. Using XCode 6.1 GM with iOS 8.1 Beta.

In 2 places inside code getting error message: 
Method 'fromRaw' has been replaced with a property 'rawValue'. When I replace .toRaw() with .rawValue getting unknown compiler error.

```
if self._attached != nil && self._attached!.toRaw() == i {
            continue
        }

  ...
  self._segmentPoints[direction.clockwise().toRaw()].0, self._segmentPoints[direction.counterclockwise().toRaw()].1)
```

What am I doing wrong? any suggestions on how to use `.rawValue`?

Comment: unknown compiler error????

Comment: @BryanChen Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 and huge code dump

Comment: post the full error message and maybe file a bug report https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: @BryanChen I think it's because of my fault.

Comment: Converting those to `rawValue` isn't the problem, it's just letting the compiler get a little further through the process of compiling your code, when it runs into what is **really** breaking it. There are several crashers in the Swift compiler, still. Here's how to find it: comment out half your code. Still crashing? Comment out the other half? Fixed? Then go piece by piece of the suspect code until you have it narrowed down...

Answer (score 0):

toRaw and fromRaw are cancel by new version of xcode

replace by "rawValue"
eg:

```
    enum Rank: Int{
    case Ace = 1
    case Two,Three,Four
    case Jack,Queen,King
    func simpleDesc() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Ace:
            return "ace"
        case .Jack:
            return "jack"
        default:
            return String(self.rawValue)
        }
    }

}


    let ace = Rank.Jack
    let aceRawValue = ace.rawValue
    println(aceRawValue)


    let b = Rank(rawValue: 5)
    println(b!.simpleDesc())
```